# How can I send to the API the updated toggle value?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What im trying to do is to update the value to true or false in the backend.
When the app is started I get the value from the backend which might be true or false.
The user has a toggle that can change it to true-false.

```
  const toggleSwitch = () => setShareLocation((prevState) => !prevState);
  const anotherFunction = () => {
    const shareStatusCheck = {
      sharedLocation: shareLocation,
      userID: userID,
      trusteePhone: trusteePhone,
    };

    axios
      .post(USER_API + 'modifyShareLocation', shareStatusCheck)
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log('SharedLocation status: ', res?.data?.data?.selectedTrustees);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error from editShareLocation: ', err);
      });
  };

  const callAll = () => {
    toggleSwitch();
    anotherFunction();
  };


return(
 <View style={styles.buttonNormal}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTextNormal}>{i18n.t('shareLocation')}</Text>
    <Switch
       trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#4E2C70' }}
       thumbColor={shareLocation ? '#FFFFFF' : '#f4f3f4'}
       onChange={callAll}
       value={shareLocation}
   />
 </View>
)
```

The problem is that when the Switch is changed from true to false, in the `shareStatusCheck` params it will be false, and If I change the Switch to false, the `shareStatusCheck` will be true.
Its like the shareLocation inside shareStatusChekc object it's one time behind.

How can shareStatusCheck get the correct value from the toggle switch?

Comment: Instead of calling `anotherFunction` you could use `useEffect` and if the `shareLocation` value changes you'll make the request

Comment: You can try @RubenSmn 's suggestion if you have a lot of stuff to handle based on the new switch value... or you can try doing both things inside the toggle function...

Answer (score -1):

Use negation like in `setShareLocation`.

```
  const toggleSwitch = () => setShareLocation((prevState) => !prevState);
  const anotherFunction = () => {
    const shareStatusCheck = {
      sharedLocation: !shareLocation,
...
    };
...
  };
```